# Finding an interval for rational numbers with a high denominator

Tags: problem-solving

I came across a [Tricki article](http://www.tricki.org/article/Finding_an_interval_for_rational_numbers_with_a_high_denominator) with the above title, but it was a stub that didn't say how to do that particular trick.

I've run into this issue a few times before (can't put my finger on which contexts at the moment), and I was wondering how you do it in the sense the author meant.

Comment: There are no rationals in lowest terms with denominator smaller than 3 in the interval $(-1/3, 1/3)$, for instance.

Comment: Please describe more fully what you are trying to do.  It sort of sounds like the fact that there are no rationals in $(\frac 14,\frac 13)$ with denominator less than $7$, but that is a guess.

Comment: @Ross Millikan  Yes, that's it

Comment: "That's it" is not a sufficient response to my request for clarification.  What is your question?  You should not expect people to click through and read an article.  Even if I had I would not understand what you are asking.

Comment: My question is: given an interval, how do you figure out the lowest denominator that can occur in an interval, when reduced to lowest terms?

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer > 1. Then, the interval 
$$ I_n = \left [ \frac{n-1}n, 1 \right ) $$
contains rationals with denominator $> n$.

Proof: Suppose $\frac{a}b \in n$ and $b < n.$ Clearly $a < b$ so

$$\frac{a}{b} \le \frac{b-1}{b} = 1 - \frac{1}b \le1 -  \frac{1}{n-1} = \frac{n-2}{n-1} < \frac{n-1}{n} $$
which cannot happen.